# jsGettext Library "ReferenceError: str is not defined" in firefox

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox, gettext, referenceerror

The gettext.js library is not working, when I run the `"index.html"` I got `"ReferenceError: str is not defined"`

```
this.LCmessages[lang] = new jsGettext.Parse(str);
```

Where `str` variable is coming from? How do i solve this?

I've use gettext.js version 0.1.0 on Firefox version 21.0 - Windows 7 64 bits

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: I can't find any solution...

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you didn't define `str` variable you're trying to parse. Check that you initialized it.

So what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah i figured it out, but being a library should not have to initialize the variable? Can I change the library?

Comment: I put this: "var str = 0" and returned to give another error: "TypeError: jsGettext.Parse is not a constructor"